# Update from Xcode 7.3 to Xcode 8 leads a lot of language errors

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I've added to pod file:

```
config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
```

post_install do |installer|

```
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
      config.build_settings['CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES'] = 'YES'
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
    end

    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
      config.build_settings['CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES'] = 'YES'
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
    end
  end
end
```

I used Xcode 7.3 and Swift 2.3 and all works perfect now I updated to Xcode 8 and got many issues in pods files. So I've tried to update it as I described above with specifying Swift version = 3 but I still have a lot issues in different cocoa pods libraries.

Comment: What version of CocoaPods are you using?

Comment: @Mike it's 0.39.0

Comment: I had a bunch of issues related to Cocoapods and Swift 3 + Xcode 8. I would check out a newer version and maybe try again.

Comment: @Mike maybe should I use instead 2.3 version? As I found here: http://blog.bitrise.io/2016/09/17/cocoapods-issue-and-fix-with-xcode-8.html

Comment: They're up to v1.1.... I would give those a try...

Answer (score 0):

Use deintegrate pod to remove all the current pods from your project. Then install the pods again..